# Reflexive Schema Validation & Definition

Tags: xsd

Can can someone help me on how to define a xsd for this.

I also want enforce validation at schema level such that based on the attribute value given, only the corresponding child tags will be displayed (reflexive based on the attribute value).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <sample-tag type="one">
    <one></one>
</sample-tag>
<sample-tag type="two">
    <two></two>
</sample-tag>
<sample-tag type="three">
    <three></three>
</sample-tag>
<sample-tag type="onetwo">
    <one></one>
    <two></two>
</sample-tag>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with XSD. Check if this is possible with [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If I take your sample XML as an approximation, then strictly speaking there is one way to achieve the effect you want: it is called [xsi:type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type). I personally dislike xsi:type, so I consider this answer rather an academic exercise.

If you agree with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <sample-tag xsi:type="one"> 
        <one></one> 
    </sample-tag> 
    <sample-tag xsi:type="two"> 
        <two></two> 
    </sample-tag> 
    <sample-tag xsi:type="three"> 
        <three></three> 
    </sample-tag> 
    <sample-tag xsi:type="onetwo"> 
        <one></one> 
        <two></two> 
    </sample-tag> 
</root>
```

... then this XSD would give you what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sample-tag" type="sample-tag"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="sample-tag" abstract="true"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="one">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sample-tag">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="one"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="two">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sample-tag">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="two"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="three">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sample-tag">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="three"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="onetwo">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sample-tag">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="one"/>
                    <xsd:element name="two"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

If xsi:type is out of question, and XSD 1.1, then you have to go with @Pangea's answer.